# Send parameters to alloc_cb

Tags: libuv

I want to use libuv to send files over TCP.
My problem is with `uv_read_start` for reading the content of the file.

To do that, I first send the size of the file, so I make a static `malloc(sizeof(uint64_t))` in the `alloc_cb` to read the size.
After that I have to make `malloc(size)` to allocate the necessary amount of memory to fill all the file in memory (I absolutely want to have the file like this in memory).

But I don't know how to pass the argument `size` to the `alloc_cb` (I don't want to use global variable).
Is there a way to do that without global variable?
Perhaps a way totaly different to do the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I see that `handle->data` contain a `void*` so we can put in exactly what we want.
Before calling `uv_read_start` store the size in the stream handle `stream->data = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));` and `*(size_t *)(stream->data) = size;`, and reuse it in `alloc_cb` by reading `size_t rsize = *(size_t*)(handle->data);`.
After that you must free this buffer.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As OP mentioned, using the `void *` field is an option.

The other is to use inheritance (if using C++) or inheritance-style hackery in C.

**For C++ :** we use inheritance.

```
struct my_struct: public uv_handle_t {
    size_t size;
};
```

You can pass a pointer to this structure to `alloc_cb` (since `my_struct` inherits from `handle`), and then cast it back to type `my_struct`:

```
my_struct * s = reinterpret_cast<my_struct*>(handle);
```

**For C :** we don't have inheritance, so we need a bit of a hack:

```
struct my_struct {
    uv_handle_t handle;
    size_t size;
};
```

Then call `alloc_cb` after casting a pointer to an object of type `my_struct` to `uv_handle_t` (`(uv_handle_t*) s`), and cast back to `my_struct` inside `alloc_cb`:

```
my_struct * s = (my_struct*) handle;
```

The C method is explained in more details (though in a different context) in the book `An introduction to libuv`, release 2, at paragraph 8.4 "Passing data to worker thread" (see [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/introduction.html)).